# Run multiple commands at once in the same terminal

Tags: linux, bash

I want to run a few commands, each of which doesn't quit until <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed. Is there something I can run to run all of them at once, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will quit them all? They can share the terminal output.

Specifically, I have the compass compiler, coffeescript compiler, and a custom command that watches for file changes all running watching for file changes. I don't want to load up a terminal for each command.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

This bash script is for N parallel threads. Each argument is a command.

`trap` will kill all subprocesses when SIGINT is catched.
`wait $PID_LIST` is waiting each process to complete.
When all processes have completed, the program exits.

```
#!/bin/bash

for cmd in "$@"; do {
  echo "Process \"$cmd\" started";
  $cmd & pid=$!
  PID_LIST+=" $pid";
} done

trap "kill $PID_LIST" SIGINT

echo "Parallel processes have started";

wait $PID_LIST

echo
echo "All processes have completed";
```

Save this script as `parallel_commands` and make it executable.
This is how to use this script:

```
parallel_commands "cmd arg0 arg1 arg2" "other_cmd arg0 arg2 arg3"
```

Example:

```
parallel_commands "sleep 1" "sleep 2" "sleep 3" "sleep 4"
```

Start 4 parallel sleep and waits until "sleep 4" finishes.

Comment: Very cool. Trap is what I was looking for. I edited your answer to include `wait`, which will suppress unnecessary "process x exited" messages.

Comment: @MTsoul, `wait` is better than while loop. I've improved my script with your suggestion. It also works for N parallel commands now.

Comment: What about running each cmd on a single distinct core? Should I run like: ./parallel_commands "taskset -c 0 cmd arg0 arg1 arg2" "taskset -c 1 other_cmd arg0 arg2 arg3"  or  taskset -c 2 ./parallel_commands "taskset -c 0 cmd arg0 arg1 arg2" "taskset -c 1 other_cmd arg0 arg2 arg3"

Comment: So great. Now i have some commands which are in bash scrip and i want to run them **parallel**?

Comment: why does it return "[1]   Done                    $cmd"  and not the actual command ???

Comment: @BrianJosephSpinos I guess this is what your shell print when something goes in background.

Comment: hm... Im using mac terminal, is there a way to show the value of that variable?

Comment: Do you want STDOUT or the exit value?

Comment: This is clever, but unnecessary (See Ole Tange's answer, below)

Comment: nice,can we also trigger the command in one go, and then both the commands will run in different terminal but parallely.

Answer (score 119):

Based on comment of @alessandro-pezzato. 
Run multiples commands by using `&` between the commands.

Example:

```
$ sleep 3 & sleep 5 & sleep 2 &
```

It's will execute the commands in background.

Comment: Hi @OleTange, I don't know the difference. I tried `&!` and `&` and both worked equally.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I change the code and remove the exclamation mark.

Comment: Control-C doesn't fully end all parallel commands when execute like this, they will keep running in the background. What's the correct way to end the execution of all the commands?

Comment: Run fg and then press Ctrl+C, repeat as needed

Comment: this runs them in sequence for me

Answer (score 40):

Use [GNU Parallel](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parallel/):

```
(echo command1; echo command2) | parallel
parallel ::: command1 command2
```

To kill:

```
parallel ::: command1 command2 &
PID=$!
kill -TERM $PID
kill -TERM $PID
```

Reference to [gnu.org site](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Comment: @Oatman: It should be, but GNU parallel is not in all distributions. For example, RHEL 7 doesn't appear to have a package readily available.

Comment: Is it possible to track the PID of the parallel process that starts multiple processes and terminate them all by terminating parent parallel?

Comment: @StefanMajewsky: `parallel` is in the EPEL repository.

Comment: The citation warning/noise is really annoying! It pollutes the output, you can silence it yes, but why the hell should one do this? Imagine the chaos if all open source tools would have done this!

Comment: @JavadSadeqzadeh Did you read https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/doc/citation-notice-faq.txt

Comment: I just read it but I'm not convinced at all. The developer claims he will not be able to maintain the tool if not supported by citations, this implies that the tool will die if he stops maintaining it. This is not open-source then, open-source projects don't rely on a single contributor. If he doesn't have time to maintain it, fine, others will do if there's enough interest. Also, this is not a huge codebase and doesn't require a lot of maintenance effort IMO, so this look like a false claim.

Answer (score 5):

It can be done with simple Makefile:

```
sleep%:
        sleep $(subst sleep,,$@)
        @echo $@ done.
```

Use `-j` option.

```
$ make -j sleep3 sleep2 sleep1
sleep 3
sleep 2
sleep 1
sleep1 done.
sleep2 done.
sleep3 done.
```

Without `-j` option it executes in serial.

```
$ make -j sleep3 sleep2 sleep1
sleep 3
sleep3 done.
sleep 2
sleep2 done.
sleep 1
sleep1 done.
```

You can also do dry run with `-n' option.

```
$ make -j -n sleep3 sleep2 sleep1
sleep 3
sleep 2
sleep 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I am suggesting a much simpler utility I just wrote. It's currently called par, but will be renamed soon to either parl or pll, haven't decided yet.

https://github.com/k-bx/par

API is as simple as:

```
par "script1.sh" "script2.sh" "script3.sh"
```

Prefixing commands can be done via:

```
par "PARPREFIX=[script1] script1.sh" "script2.sh" "script3.sh"
```

Comment: After trying and failing to do what you describe above using gnu parallel I succeeded on the first try using your utility. Nice work!

Comment: The first: `parallel ::: "script1.sh" "script2.sh" "script3.sh"` The second would normally use --tag: 
`parallel --tag ::: "script1.sh" "script2.sh" "script3.sh"`

Answer (score -16):

To run multiple commands just add `&&` between two commands like this: `command1 && command2`

And if you want to run them in two different terminals then you do it like this:

```
gnome-terminal -e "command1" && gnome-terminal -e "command2"
```

This will open 2 terminals with `command1` and `command2` executing in them.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is incorrect. It runs `command2` **after** `command1` and only if `command1` succeeds. Try `sleep 3 && sleep 3` and you will see it takes 6s.

Comment: command1 && command2 doesn't start executing at once. it will be executed one after another (considering success scenario for command).