# php flock example

Tags: php, linux

In php.net some one has commented that 
"In some case, when more than 20 requests per second try to do exclusive flock on the same file, the scripts stuck".

I know this is true as my application has got stuck and when i remove flock from my application , my script is working fine.

I try to reproduce an example for "In some case, when more than 20 requests per second try to do exclusive flock on the same file, the scripts stuck"." but got no luck.

Can someone write an example for the same ?

Comment: SO is not a "gimme stuff" kind of site. Present your own solutions, explain the problems with it and we might be able to help you.

Comment: why are you using a lock file with that kind of activity - there's probably a better way

Comment: For what it is worth, the comment you are reading is 4 years old. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php#87181

Comment: The "better way" (suggested by @MarkBaker) is probably a database, at least `SQLite`, which means: There is _never_ a reason to not use a database :)

Comment: yes, i am using flock for incrementing memcache value.
but i really wana know why my apache requests are getting stuck

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos i know its 4 year old comment but i faced it today
so want to know if its true

Comment: Could it be something else in your code that is adding the stall/wait time. Maybe it's time to show some of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) or [`parallel`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel) is your friend. Write a small php script that locks your file. Then execute it through xargs X number of times and see if it takes down your httpd server.

Also found this bash script on SO: [Run parallel multiple commands at once in the same terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909685/run-parallel-multiple-commands-at-once-in-the-same-terminal)

Comment: i already tried that , but flock is causing script to wait but not hanging the script

Comment: Did you try a load tester? Here's a few: [jmeter](http://blazemeter.com/), [blitz.io](https://www.blitz.io/), [Load Impact](http://loadimpact.com/)