# Bash run two commands and get output from both

Tags: bash, shell

I need to run two commands in parallel and get the output from both in the same shell.

Edit:

I am trying to run multiple long-running commands that watch the file system and compile various things for me (CoffeeScript, Jade, sass).

Comment: What problems are you facing?

Comment: What are you doing to run them in parallel?

Comment: possible duplicate:[Run parallel multiple commands at once in the same terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10909685/2033671)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking at wait command in bash. Consider this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FAIL=0
echo "starting"

./script1 &
./script2 &

for job in `jobs -p`
do
   echo $job
   wait $job || let "FAIL+=1"
done

echo $FAIL

if [ "$FAIL" == "0" ];
then
    echo "All jobs completed!"
else
    echo "Jobs FAILED: ($FAIL)"
fi
```

[Courtesy](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/010717.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
command1 &
command2 &
```

They're both running in parallel; their output goes to the screen.

Comment: You may want to add a 'wait' to the end of the script