# Parallel Run and Task-Core Assignment

Tags: linux, parallel-processing

I use the script suggested in [Run parallel multiple commands at once in the same terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909685/run-parallel-multiple-commands-at-once-in-the-same-terminal) in order to run some applications in parallel. It works fine, however, I want to stick each application to a single core and my question is how to make sure that each of those applications runs on a distinct core? Where to insert "taskset -c"s ? Before each application's run command inside the script and/or before the script's command itself when I run it from the terminal??

Answer (score 4):

Newer versions of GNU Parallel supports progressing ctrl-c.

Linux is pretty good at scheduling tasks, so only use `taskset` after you have timed that it really does benefit performance.

To get a number 0..n-1 (e.g. 0..7) the tempting solution is:

```
# This is wrong
... | parallel taskset -c $(({#}%8)) {}
```

This, however, will only work if jobs take exactly the same amount of time. With 8 jobslots if job 1..7 takes 2 seconds, and job 8 takes 1 second. Then job 9 will be run while job 1 is running.

A better solution is to define your own replacement string that counts jobslots 0..7:

```
echo '--rpl "{%%} \$_=slot()-1"' >> ~/.parallel/config
... | parallel taskset -c {%%} {}
```

Comment: This isn't quite going to work, because {#} substitutes for the overall job number, not the current slot the job is running in.  So if you want to run 1000 jobs on eight processors, when the ninth job starts up, taskset will display a "taskset: failed to set pid 0's affinity: Invalid argument" error because it will try to run "taskset -c 9", which doesn't exist.  Run "parallel taskset -c $(({#}%7)) {}" instead.

Comment: @Ole Tange Can you add an option to parallel so it can do this itself? Also, you might want to disclose you're the developer of parallel (for which I thank you)

Comment: Thanks, this is excellent. Note that if you do use {%}, some processes might not execute as the core numbers start at 0 - so, say if you have 8 cores, the 8th core is core 7 whereas {%} will produce 8 (and result in an affinity error). I used `-j7` (i.e., num cores - 1) along with {%} to circumvent the issue. Yes, you won't get to use core 0, but in that case, you might be better off with the `taskset -c $(({#}%7)) {}` method.