# Run two run-until-cancel commands at once with Fabric

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, parallel-processing, automation, gruntjs, fabric

I use [Fabric](http://fabfile.org)  to develop, manage and deploy my Django sites. I've toned my workflow into an agile beast... And yet, my scope for laziness seems infinite...

I've recently started to use a lot of Bootstrap. I feel as if I *could*  reimplement most of Grunt's functionality in Fabric but that's really not what I'd like to do. What I want is a Fabric command that simultaneously runs:

- (with `lcd` into my bootstrap directory) `grunt watch` to auto-rebuild my Bootstrap output if I edit it
- `./manage.py runserver` to run a dev server for Django (which also auto-rebuilds)

Both of these commands will run indefinitely until I cancel them... And that seems like a problem. If I used Fabric's `@parallel` decorator, I'm not going to have any control over the commands, am I? The output (while not critical) is also going to be a bit messed up.

So given this situation, what's the best way of handling two commands like this and automating them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run parallel multiple commands at once in the same terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909685/run-parallel-multiple-commands-at-once-in-the-same-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

In similar scenarios, where I want to run multiple processes locally during development (web app, asset builder, database server...) I typically use [supervisor](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/supervisor).

Once configured, you can control (ie. start, stop, etc.) all processes using the `supervisorctl` command.