# how to process several commands concurrently and continue the rest only after all is done on ubuntu

Tags: shell, concurrency, ubuntu-14.04

To be specific, I have two command need to be run in shell on Ubuntu ***at the same time***, like ***command_A*** and ***command_B***. And I have some other commands need to be run only after ***command_A*** and ***command_B*** has finished, named as ***command_rest***. In addition, ***command_A*** and ***command_B*** run in separate terminals and when they are finished they can close themselves. This maybe need techniques related to *signal* and *wait* and *gnome-terminal* i guess, but i cannot find a solution.

Comment: This is perfectly possible and please let us know what options you have explored/tried?

Comment: i believe this is what you are looking for[ \[Answer\]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10909842/5924412)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run parallel multiple commands at once in the same terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909685/run-parallel-multiple-commands-at-once-in-the-same-terminal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this using a fifo to synchronise:

```
# Once in either Terminal
mkfifo A B

# In first Terminal
( echo CommandA; sleep 3; echo done > A ) &

# In second Terminal
( echo CommandB; sleep 8; echo done > B ) &

# In third Terminal
read < A; read < B; echo Rest
```

Basically, before `Rest` can run, it has to have read something from both `A` and `B` and nothing will arrive for it to read until `CommandA` has finished and written to `A` and also `CommandB` has finished and written to `B`.

The above is just an example that echoes `CommandA` and `CommandB` and `Rest` instead of running commands that I don't have. You will actually want something like this (I have modified it so you can be in different directories in the various Terminals)

```
# Once in either Terminal
mkfifo  /tmp/A  /tmp/B

# In first Terminal
( CommandA; echo done > /tmp/A ) &

# In second Terminal
( CommandB; echo done > /tmp/B ) &

# In third Terminal
read < /tmp/A; read < /tmp/B; commandRest
```

Comment: I wrote this into fifo.sh and run it using command ". fifo.sh", and its output likes the following: CommandA\n CommandB\n Rest\n [2]- Done (echo CommandA; sleep 3; echo done >A )\n [3]+  Done (echo CommandB; sleep 8; echo done >B)\n   (\n is for another line)(the last line showed up when i enter another command in)   It seems already worked, but i was just curious about what does the output mean at the last two lines.

Comment: The other lines are just so I can show a working example without anyone needing to have your `CommandA`, `CommandB` and `CommandRest`. I have updated it now so please look again.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer~ Maybe a specific example will clarify my question. For instance, if i want to use "read" command in two terminals and then after each has received keyboard, I write "echo finished inputing" as commandRest. I tried to implement with your method but it won't work because i will stuck at  the input. And if i try to open new terminal using "gnome-terminal -e" command in CommandA and CommandB, it can show two new terminals simultaneously, but the commandRest won't wait for my input and just echo out. So i want to know how to fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't see which part is causing you a problem:-) I have made a small update to the code so you can be in different directories in the various Terminals - maybe that will help. I don't see how your `CommandRest` can possibly do anything till it has read the word `done` from both fifos - it cannot.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't seem to be doing too well with fifo-based synchronisation, you could maybe try using **GNU Parallel**, which, when installed creates a symbolic link called `sem` that acts as a semaphore.

So, in Terminal 1, you would do:

```
sem -j 2 --id mark CommandA
```

and in Terminal 2, you would do:

```
sem -j 2 --id mark CommandB
```

Then, anywhere you wanted to wait for both to finish, you would do:

```
sem --id mark --wait ; CommandRest
```

Comment: Thanks for additional advice. I tried `sleep 10` as CommandA and CommandB and it worked well. However, when I used `read` as both `CommandA` and `CommandB`, `echo` "received" as `CommandRest` ,  and the first two will stuck, and can't receive any keyboard input. When I closed the first two terminals, the third terminal indeed shows "received". So the problem is that the command `read` cannot work well under this circumstance. DO you know how to fix that?