# Run python commands in parallel in Linux shell scripting

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have a script which gets input from the user through command line arguments. It processes the arguments and starts running python commands. For Example:

```
./run.sh p1 p2 p3 p4
python abc.py p1 p4
python xyz.py p2 p3
```

where `p1`, `p2`, `p3` and `p4` can be of any type.

I need to run both of these python commands in parallel and in two different terminals. How can I do it so that I don't need to wait for 1 command to finish in order to start the next command?

I tried GNU parallel but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I worked on Python project that used parallelism for their hydrodynamic modeling and they utilized OpenMPI. If you want to see how they implemented it you might find something on their github: https://github.com/GeoscienceAustralia/anuga_core

Comment: There is a wonderful answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10909842/5381704

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running each process in the background by adding `&` to the end of the command.

```
python script1.py arg1 arg2 &
python script2.py arg1 arg2 &

echo "Running scripts in parallel"
wait # This will wait until both scripts finish
echo "Script done running"
```

[More Info](https://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html)

Comment: Remember a final "wait"

Answer (score 0):

Your task is not where GNU Parallel excels, but it can be done:

```
parallel ::: "python abc.py p1 p4" "python xyz.py p2 p3"
```