# Start multiple commands in parallel in Linux and wait for all of them to finish

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I am running a shell script that basically does a "cd dir && git pull" in multiple directories that are part of one big app. After each of them is successfully updated, the script runs a "npm run build", but given that the update is on 30+ directories, the process takes quite some time.

I figured it would be easier if each of the 30 different "git pull" operations are *parallelized*, but I have no idea from where to start. I was thinking to span separate threads for the "git pull" commands and I'm familiar with a couple of options to do a "detached terminal" command on Linux but they all prevent the main terminal from understading when the detached command has finished its work (when all the asynchronous "git pull" opearations are done).

Here's a simplified version of my script:

```
cd ./app/dir1 && git pull
cd ./app/dir2 && git pull
...
cd ./app && npm run build
```

The question is not related to Git or NPM in any way.

**To summarize: I would like to spawn multiple commands asynchronously, wait for all of them to complete, and continue with further commands afterwards.**

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of ["Run parallel multiple commands at once in the same terminal"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909685/run-parallel-multiple-commands-at-once-in-the-same-terminal): that question is about spawning parallel processes *which run until they are interrupted* whereas this question is about spawning parallel processes *which exit on their own*. However, the answers to that question also apply to this one. It's unfortunate that there cannot be an answer here saying as much.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds you look for the `parallel` tool http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ .

They have an quick intro video: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Something like this could be working for your example

```
# run in parallel
ls ./app/dir* | parallel 'cd {} && git pull'
# the last command without parallel
cd ./app && npm run build
```