# Docker run multiple commands asynchronously and kill both if one fails

Tags: angular, linux, bash, docker

I have an angular production build running in a docker container and I would like to run the `ng build` and `ng lint` asynchronously.

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909685/run-parallel-multiple-commands-at-once-in-the-same-terminal) which means my command would look like `ng build --prod & ng lint`. The problem is that if the first command fails before the second command finishes, my execution keeps running. (ex: The lint bombs after 10s because of a missed semicolon, but the build finishes after 6 minutes successfully. My command says it was successful even though my lint failed and continues to publish). My solution around this is to have `ng build --prod && ng lint` but this takes more time to finish.

Is there a way to have both commands run asynchronously and if one of the executions bomb out then the whole command stops?

Comment: did you explore https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/blob/HEAD/docs/npm-run-all.md

Comment: You'd generally run those commands in your Dockerfile, not in a standalone container.  A `RUN` command will fail the image build if it exits with a failing status.

Comment: @AakashGarg that is exactly what I'm looking for. If you want to submit it as an answer, I will accept it in a couple hours to see if there is a solution that doesn't involve a 3rd party library.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am running `ENTRYPOINT` in my Dockerfile which runs a script from my package.json that lints and build everything for me. My `RUN` basically sets up a linux environment for me to build in.

Comment: That rebuilds your application every time you launch the container, and especially when you're talking about multi-minute builds that seems incredibly inefficient.

Comment: @DavidMaze the container is only launched when someone on my team pushes changes to our repository for code review and when changes are merged into master

Comment: At that point, have your CI system build an image with the code compiled in.  Developers can build and launch the container themselves if they need to do extended testing.

Comment: @DavidMaze I feel like we are arguing over nothing right now. We have a auto build process on bamboo that uses the docker image to build the angular portion of our project. Every time we push code to our repository (that is on a branch), bamboo generates a docker container based on our Dockerfile, and then builds our project. After the build is done it destroys the container and frees up resources so a different team with different specifications can use that build node. I'm just trying to find a way to make that build process faster for my team.

Comment: We may run a build or a lint individually to make sure our code is valid, but we don't run a full production build on our machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go for something like :-

https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/blob/HEAD/docs/npm-run-all.md

It gives you various options which will be usefull in all current and future scenarios.